# Script inside href how to

Tags: javascript

I'm using this link:

```
<a href="javascript:location='http://www.linkimprov.com/?ref='+encodeURI(location.href).substring(7);"></a>
```

It is intended for use as a bookmark. When clicked it redirects the user to an url that takes the previous location removing the 7 first characters from it.

Instead of removing the first 7 characters from '+encodeURI(location.href)' I want it to do this:

```
if(encodeURI(location.href).match(/http:\/\//))
{
encodeURI(location.href).substring(7);
}    
if(encodeURI(location.href).match(/https:\/\//))
{
encodeURI(location.href).substring(8);
}
if(encodeURI(location.href).match(/^www\./))
{
encodeURI(location.href).substring(4);
}
```

How could make this work inside the href?

thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly. But, you can write whatever JS you want and turn it into a javascript URI. See http://shadow2531.com/js/jsuri.html?source=(function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(%22test%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D)()%3B for an example. What it outputs is what you put in the href attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
location = 'http://www.linkimprov.com/?ref=' + encodeURI(
    location.href.match(/(?=https?:\/\/)?(?=www\.)?(.*)/)[1]
).substring(7);
```

Or in a link:

```
<a href="javascript:location='http://www.linkimprov.com/?ref='+encodeURI(location.href.match(/(?=https?:\/\/)?(?=www\.)?(.*)/)[1]).substring(7);"></a>
```

EDIT: Try this:

```
 location = 'http://www.linkimprov.com/?ref=' + encodeURI(
    location.href.match(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)/).pop()
).substring(7);
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems close to it but I just tried it with facebook and it resulted on: ebook.com =S not a bad domain though.

Comment: yes, here is the link. http://www.chusmix.com/game/?ref=www.wordreference.com/ it's the link on the top left. You can click it right there and check the url or drag it to bookmarks and see it in facebook

Comment: Sorry, it isn't working. It removes https:/ and leaves / and www. from sites that are https and when it has www. it doesn't do anything. I couldn't test it with http://

Comment: Thanks anyway, I have a raw solution but I'm not very eager to use it.

Comment: I forgot to say I tested it at www.chusmix.com/test.php

Comment: @Liso22: Try my edited answer, btw it won't kill you to click on the up arrow next to my answer

Comment: It doesn't work, same problem as before. It trims too much. Still testing it here www.chusmix.com/test.php

Comment: @Liso22: you should get rid of the `.substr()` call